# Run single folder of pytest tests in vscode

Tags: python, pytest, visual-studio-code, vscode-python

I have a sort of a "micro-service" Python repo with a setup similar to the following:

```
sample
├── bar
│   ├── src
│   │   └── main.py
│   └── tests
│       └── test_main.py
├── foo
│   ├── src
│   │   └── main.py
│   └── tests
│       └── test_main.py
└── shared
    ├── src
    │   └── main.py
    └── tests
        └── test_main.py
```

In vscode I only have the option of running *all* tests in `foo`,`bar`,`shared` or running individual test *methods* in the subfolders. What I want to do is be able to quickly run just the `foo/tests/`.

Is there some way I can configure pytest/Python to do this? I don't want to split each top level folder into its own workspace because I regularly jump back and for between them and don't want to have multiple windows per workspace open.

Comment: You can create a `pytest.ini` with `addopts = foo/tests/` under the `[pytest]` section.

Answer (score -3):

You should be able to run the command `pytest foo/tests/` in the terminal according to the 
[pytest documentation](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/usage.html)

Comment: Right but I want to be able to run this via a command in vscode.